# How to change variable value declared in a class from another class?

Tags: swift, get, set

I have a 2 viewcontrollers, in vC1 a variable `isShowListAsked : Bool = false`  is declared , on clicking map button it goes to vC2 . In vC2 there is a button named ***List***.
I want that :
after clicking ***List*** button it go back to vC1 and vC1 variable value should changed to true. But it is still remains False.

Please help me .

Thanks in advance.

On clicking ***List*** button i am able to go back to vC1 but not able to set ***isShowListAsked = true*** . i tried get{} set {}.

In vC1 :

```
class vC1 : UIViewController
 {
var isShowListAsked : Bool = false

    var IsShowListAsked : Bool {
        get {
            return isShowListAsked
        }
        set{
            isShowListAsked = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Then after clicking In vC2 :

```
class vC2 : UIViewController 
{
var vc = vC1()

 @IBAction func mapListSegmentTapped(_ sender: Any) {

       if mapListSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 
     {
       vc.IsShowListAsked = true

        }
        if mapListSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 
      {
            vc.IsShowListAsked = false
        }
   }
}
```

After going back i am checking variable value in viewWillappear()

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      print(" isshowListAsked = \(IsShowListAsked) ") // print false
   }
```

Expected Result :

```
print(" isshowListAsked = \(IsShowListAsked) ") // print True
```

Actual Result :

```
print(" isshowListAsked = \(IsShowListAsked) ") // print false
```

Comment: Just Use delegate protocols.

Comment: The problem is that you’re creating a new instance of VC1, you need to set the value on the instance you came from. Use a delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`Closures`** to solve your problem statement.

Create a `closure` in `VC2` of type `((Bool)->())?` and call it with the relevant `true/false` values in `mapListSegmentTapped(_:)` method, i.e.

```
class VC2: UIViewController {
    var handler: ((Bool)->())?

    @IBAction func mapListSegmentTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if mapListSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            self.handler?(true)
        } else if mapListSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            self.handler?(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, set this `closure` when you're `presenting` the `instance` of `VC2` from `VC1` i.e.

```
class VC1 : UIViewController {
    var isShowListAsked: Bool = false

    func onTapMapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2") as? VC2 {
            controller.handler = {[weak self] (value) in
                self?.isShowListAsked = value
                print(self?.isShowListAsked) 
            }
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```